# Contribution of gravitational waves to a maximum-entropy big bang

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, gravitational-waves

Our universe did not have a maximum-entropy big bang. If it did, then by the second law of thermodynamics we wouldn't see the universe today in a non-equilibrium state. I've seen this explained by saying that the gravitational degrees of freedom were for some reason not activated, and this was the motivation for Penrose's failed CCC theory.

Is there any simple way to estimate quantitatively how much of a contribution gravitational waves should have made to the total number of accessible states in a maximum-entropy big bang? Or is there at least some simple argument that their contribution should have been significant?

Thermodynamically, I would think that gravitational waves would act a lot like electromagnetic waves, which tended to dominate in the early universe because of the way the equation of state of a massless particle connects the scale factor to the energy density.

Comment: I'm not sure you can equate the degrees of freedom in gravitational waves with the total gravitational degrees of freedom. Consider, for example, the huge entropy of black hole solutions.